# Xamarin Studio error C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin-studio

So, I've installed Xamarin Studio, with the 2 other programs. (.NET and #GTK for .NET) (http://www.monodevelop.com/download/)
I create a new project in C#, run the Hello World program, and it tells me that there is an error (sorry it's in French) :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3644: les assemblys de référence pour le framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" sont introuvables. Pour résoudre ce problème, installez le SDK ou le Targeting Pack pour cette version de framework ou reciblez votre application vers une version du framework pour laquelle le SDK ou le Targeting Pack est installé. Les assemblys seront résolus à partir du Global Assembly Cache (GAC) et seront utilisés à la place des assemblys de référence. C'est pourquoi votre assembly peut ne pas cibler correctement le framework souhaité. (MSB3644) (PremierProjet)

It basically says that the assemblys of refence for the Framework ".NETFramework", cannot be found.

I tried to reinstall all 3 programs, but it's still not working.
Thanks for your help.

Here's the message in English:

> Warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Comment: what platfrom is this on Windows? if so it use the native .NET 4.5 implementation which I'm guessing you should install on yr machine or change the project settings to build against one you have.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert Yes it's on Windows, and as I said, I installed .NET 4.5

Comment: This looks like an issue with PCL profiles. Could you try the workaround from the Matt's blog here http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/

Comment: Try installing the Windows developer pack - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772

Answer (score 0):

The gtk# version used by xamarin studio is not the one available on the monodevelop website and is not compatible

Use the installer from the xamarin website instead.